# How can I write a test to handle an expected exception?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

How can I test for a function that throws an expected exception? Here is the function that throws the exception:

```
(defn seq-of-maps?
  "Tests for a sequence of maps, and throws a custom exception if not."
  [s-o-m]
  (if-not (seq? s-o-m)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "s-o-m is not a sequence"))
    (if-not (map? (first s-o-m))
      (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "s-o-m is not a sequence of maps."))
      true)))
```

I want to design a test like the following in which an exception is thrown and caught and then compared. The following does not work:

```
(deftest test-seq-of-maps
  (let [map1  {:key1 "val1"}
        empv  []
        s-o-m (list {:key1 "val1"}{:key2 "val2"})
        excp1 (try 
                (seq-of-maps? map1)
                (catch Exception e (.getMessage e)))]
    (is (seq-of-maps? s-o-m))
    (is (not (= excp1 "s-o-m is not a sequence")))))
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Testing util.test.core

FAIL in (test-seq-of-maps) (core.clj:27)
expected: (not (= excp1 "s-o-m is not a sequence"))
  actual: (not (not true))

Ran 2 tests containing 6 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.
```

Obviously, I am missing something about writing tests. I am having trouble figuring that out. My project was set up with lein new, and I am running the tests with lein test.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expect failure in a unit test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852092/how-do-i-expect-failure-in-a-unit-test)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The last assertion in your test is incorrect; it should be `(is (= excp1 "s-o-m is not a sequence"))` since map1 isn't a seq of maps.

Aside from that, it's probably clearer to use [`(is (thrown? ..))` or `(is (thrown-with-msg? ...))`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/is) to check for thrown exceptions.

**Example:**

```
(t/is (thrown? java.lang.ClassCastException (s/valid? ::sut/int-value "x"))))
```

Note that you just write classname as a symbol. Use `java.lang.Exception` if you don't care about the exact `Exception`.